# How to get informed about phone state, when my app is destroyed. i.e, removed from memory?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

Tried BroadcastReceiver, but only working when the app is not destroyed. When I go to background apps list and remove app by swiping, cannot receive any information about phone state. What I need is to get phone state and access call logs inorder to get call number and duration and save it into a database.

Comment: You can use a service to receive the information about phone state. The service will keep alive when the app is killed. In addition, the foreground service can keep alive when the phone is in the doze.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. You might know about Truecaller app. It gets notified about a call, even in the dead state and shows a pop up about the caller. I had verified running services in developer options. Found out, when ever there is a call, the Truecaller starts a service called "IdentifyCallerService". How come is this possible when the app is dead?

Comment: I don't know about Truecaller app at all. I had searched it and I cann't make sure what the principle is. But the key of the issue still is keeping alive. The Truecaller  ought to starts the service when call the onReceive method of the the BroadcastReceiver. There is a [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4164842e-2399-4bb7-a44e-0929a9a3c04e/how-to-keep-my-broadcastreceiver-alive-when-i-close-the-app?forum=xamarinandroid) about keeping the BroadcastReceiver alive when the app is closed.